# PHP dns_get_record raises an error with working dns resolution in system

Tags: php, dns

On a linux, rather fresh installation, I am running in a problem with calls to dns_get_record:

```
$> php -r "var_dump(dns_get_record('google.com', DNS_A));"
PHP Warning:  dns_get_record(): A temporary server error occured. in Command line code on line 1
bool(false)
```

The dns resolution seems to work otherwise on the system.

```
$> getent hosts google.com
xxxx:...:xxxx google.com
```

After looking around for a while, I am stuck. It seems to be a problem in the PHP configuration, but I could not find what options are of interest for the problem...

---

As an additional information, PHP succeeds in running some other net functions, such as gethostbyname

```
$> php -r "var_dump(gethostbyname('google.com'));"
string(15) "142. ..."
```

And the provided ip is indeed right for accessing google...

---

For a bit of context, the issue was detected through an installation of Nextcloud on an Archlinux.

*references*

- https://github.com/termux/termux-packages/issues/1225
- https://github.com/nextcloud/server/issues/27870

  Here the issue is the result of the php command that differs from the reporter.

Comment: For those still interested, the situation has been resolved, but I do not know how... I had fixed it with a change in my nextcloud instance code but have updated it since and the problem has not been back.

Answer (score 0):

You can try a PHP library for that.
A custom PHP library allows you to have more control over PHP/DNS requests.

In the case of your scenario, you can handle the nameserver you make the DNS requests. Eg. ('8.8.8.8')

[PHP-BLUE-LIBRARY-DNS](https://github.com/bluelibraries/dns)

```php
     // Let's customize the DNS request handler - TCP

     $dnsHandler = (new TCP())
            ->setPort(53)
            ->setNameserver('8.8.8.8')
            ->setTimeout(3) // limit execution to 3 seconds
            ->setRetries(5); // allows 5 retries if response fails
        
        // Let's initialize the DNS records service
        $dnsRecordsService = new DnsRecords($dnsHandler);
        
        // let's get some TXT records from `bluelibraries.com`
        $records = $dnsRecordsService->get('bluelibraries.com', RecordTypes::TXT);
        
        // let's display them
        print_r($records);
```

Comment: Thanks for reacting to it. If it needs modification, we can use other net functions (as they work) such as the `gethostbyname`. Also, in the code you provide, you enforce to use google's dns resolver, in my case that was not the server being contacted directly.